# Inverse of a non-negative matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Under what conditions, if all elements of a positive definite matrix are non-negative implies that its inverse also only has non-negative elements.

How do you approach this?

Comment: Hint: for $2\times 2$ matrices, it is easily seen to be equivalent to $A$ diagonal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: If a non-negative matrix $A$ has $a_{ij} > 0$ with
$i \ne j$, and a non-negative matrix $B$ has all its diagonal
elements strictly positive, then $(AB)_{ij} \ge a_{ij} b_{jj} > 0$.